# How do you read files on desktop with jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I launched `Jupyter Notebook`, created a new notebook in `python`, imported the necessary `libraries` and tried to access a `.xlsx` file on the desktop with this `code`:

`haber = pd.read_csv('filename.xlsx')`

but error keeps popping up. Want a reliable way of accessing this file on my desktop without incurring any error response

Comment: something like `pd.read_csv('/home/<username>/Desktop/filename.xlsx')`

Comment: Where is your python file located? Is there at your `desktop` too?

Comment: Did you figure this out @prince asamoah?

Answer (score 2):

This is an obvious path problem, because your notebook is not booted on the desktop path, you must indicate the absolute path to the desktop file, or the relative path relative to the jupyter boot directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux

```
/home/(your user name)/Desktop/(your filename)
```

if you are on windows

```
C:\Users\(your user name)\Desktop\( your filename)
```

and if your python file is on same path where dataset file is then just give the file name with extension

Answer (score 2):

You will need to enter the full path of your excel file.

First:

Open your excel file, right click on the file and click on "Copy path to clipboard".

Second:

Next paste your path in your script. Mine looks something like this:

```
#only using one backslash "\"
'C:\Users\...YourFileName.xlsx'
```

Third:

You will likely have to modify this path by adding two "\" instead of one "\" in each spot you only see one backslash.

For example, my new path would now look like this:

```
#using two backslashes now "\\"
'C:\\Users\\...YourFileName.xlsx'
```

An example of your final output will look like this:

```
haber = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\...YourFileName.xlsx')
```